# Node.js Promise within Promise within Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I *think* I'm trying to call a `Promise` within a `Promise` (maybe even within another `Promise`). In the past I try to simplify my question and I end up getting more questions, so there's a lot below:

I have the following code as a module named **myModule**:

```
let https = require('https');

module.exports.getApiOne = function(value) {
    var params = {..., path = '/api/getOne/' + value, ...};
    return getApi(params).then(response => response);
};

module.exports.getApiTwo = function(value) {
    var params = {..., path = '/api/getTwo/' + value, ...};
    return getApi(params).then(response => response);
};

function getApi(params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = https.request(params, function(res) {
            var body = [];
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body.push(chunk);
            });

           res.on('end', function() {
               try {
                   body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
               } catch (e) {
                   reject(e);
               }
               resolve(body);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
        req.end();
    });
}
```

On another file I have:

```
const status = require('myModule');
var someObject = {};

function someFunction(inputObject) {
   // initialize object
   if (!someObject[inputObject.Id]) {
       someObject[inputObject.Id] = {};
       someObject[inputObject.Id].contact = {};
    }

    // get object
    var objectForThis = someObject[inputObject.Id];

    switch (inputObject.someVal) {
        case 'test':
            //... some code
            objectForThis.stage = 'test';
            break;
        case 'hello':
            status.getApiOne('world').then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                objectForThis.stage = 'zero'
            });
            break;
        default:
            someOtherFunction(objectForThis.stage).then(response => {
                objectForThis.stage = response;
            });
            break;
    }
    someObject[inputObject.Id] = objectForThis;
}

function someOtherFunction(stage) {
    var newStage;
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        switch (stage) {
            case 'zero':
                // some code
                newStage = 'one';
            case 'one':
                status.getApiTwo('foo').then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    newStage = 'two';
                    /********************************************
                    I assume, the problem lies here, it's 
                    'resolving' (below) before this sets the new 
                    value for 'newStage'
                    ********************************************/
                });
                break;
            default:
                // do nothing
                break;
        }
    });
    resolve(newStage);
}
```

When I call

```
someFunction({id = 1, someValue = 'test'}); // sets 'stage' to 'test'
someFunction({id = 1, someValue = 'hello'}); // sets 'stage' to 'zero'
someFunction({id = 1, someValue = 'foo'}); // sets 'stage' to 'one'
someFunction({id = 1, someValue = 'bar'}); // NOT setting 'stage' to 'two'
```

Comment: Your `someFunction` should return a promise, since it is doing something asynchronous. You will need to wait for `objectForThis` to get filled.

Comment: in `someFunction` - everything in each `.then` in the switch cases is executed AFTER `someObject[inputObject.Id] = objectForThis;` is this intended?

Comment: `it's 'resolving' (below) before this sets the new  value for 'newStage'` - yes, that's correct

Comment: @Bergi not sure how to visualize what you mean by "You should just chain onto the `status.getApiTwo('foo')` call."

Comment: @JaromandaX no it's not intended. `someObject[inputObject.Id] = objectForThis` should always execute last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for why is because Promises are asynchronous:

```js
logOut("start of file");

new Promise(function(accept){
    accept();
}).then(function(){
    logOut("inside promise");
});

function makePromise(name) {
    new Promise(function(accept){
        accept();
    }).then(function(){
        logOut("inside promise inside makePromise " + name);
    });
};

logOut("value returned from makePromise: " + makePromise("one"));

try {
    // just to prove this
    makePromise("two").then(function(accept){
        accept();
    }).then(function(){
        logOut("after makePromise");
    });
} catch(err) {
    logOut("Failed to `.then` the return value from makePromise because:\n" + err.message);
}

logOut("end of file");

var outputList;
function logOut(str){
    outputList = outputList || document.getElementById("output");
    outputList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li><pre>" + str + "</pre></li>");
}
```

```html
<ol id="output"></ol>
```

As seen above, the whole program does not pause for the `.then` statement. That is why they are called Promises: because the rest of the code goes on while the Promise is waiting to be resolved. Further, as seen above, there can be a value returned from a function only if the function explicitly returns the value via the `then` keyword. JavaScript functions do not automatically return the value of the last executed statement.

Please see [my website here](https://jackgiffin.com/main/misc_help_pages/misc_promise_info.html) for more info on Promises.

In the demo below, I have attempted to fix up the fragments of the files you slapped on this question. Then, I proceeded to wrap them together into a quick single-file system I typed up

```js
(function(){"use strict";
    // NOTE: This setup code makes no attempt to accurately replicate the 
    //       NodeJS api. This setup code only tries to concisely mimics
    //        the NodeJS API solely for the purposes of preserving your code
    //         in its present NodeJS form.
    var modules = {}, require = function(fileName){return modules[fileName]};
    for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i=i+1|0)
        arguments[i]({exports: modules[arguments[i].name] = {}}, require);
})(function https(module, require){"use strict";
    ////////////// https.js //////////////
    module.exports.request = function(options, withWrapper) {
        var p, when = {}, wrapper = {on: function(name, handle){
            when[name] = handle;
        }, end: setTimeout.bind(null, function(){
            if (p === "/api/getOne/world") when.data("HTTP bar in one 1");
            else if (p === "/api/getTwo/foo") when.data("HTTP foo in two 2");
            else {console.error("Not stored path: '" + p + "'");
                  return setTimeout(when.error);}
            setTimeout(when.end); // setTimeout used for asynchrony
        }, 10 + Math.random()*30)}; // simulate random http delay
        setTimeout(withWrapper, 0, wrapper); // almost setImmediate
        return p = options.path, options = null, wrapper;
    };
    /******* IGNORE ALL CODE ABOVE THIS LINE *******/
}, function myModule(module, require) {"use strict";
    ////////////// myModule.js //////////////

    const HttpsModule = require('https');

    module.exports.getApiOne = function(value) {
        var params = {path: '/api/getOne/' + value};
        // There is no reason for `.then(response => response);`!
        // It does absolutely nothing.
        return getApi(params); // .then(response => response);
    };

    module.exports.getApiTwo = function(value) {
        var params = {path: '/api/getTwo/' + value};
        return getApi(params); // .then(response => response);
    };

    function getApi(params) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var req = HttpsModule.request(params, function(res) {
                var body = [];
                res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    body.push(chunk);
                });

               res.on('end', function() {
                   try {
                       body = body.join("");//Buffer.concat(body).toString();
                   } catch (e) {
                       reject(e);
                   }
                   resolve(body);
                });
            });
            req.on('error', function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
            req.end();
        });
    }
}, function main(module, require) {"use strict";
    ////////////// top JS script //////////////
    const MyStatusModule = require('myModule');
    const isPromise = isPrototypeOf.bind(Promise.prototype)
    var someObject = {};

    function someFunction(inputObject) {
       // initialize object
       // NOTE: Javascript IS case-sensitive, so `.Id` !== `.id`
       if (!someObject.hasOwnProperty(inputObject.id)) {
           someObject[inputObject.id] = {};
           someObject[inputObject.id].contact = {};
        }

        // get object
        var objectForThis = someObject[inputObject.id];

        switch (inputObject.someValue) {
            case 'test':
                //... some code
                return objectForThis.stage = 'test';
                break;
            case 'hello':
                return MyStatusModule.getApiOne('world').then(function (response) {
                    // console.log(response);
                    return objectForThis.stage = 'zero'
                });
                break;
            default:
                return someOtherFunction(objectForThis.stage).then(function (response) {
                    return objectForThis.stage = response;
                });
                break;
        }
    }

    function someOtherFunction(stage) {
        var newStage;
        // If you return nothing, then you would be calling `.then` on
        //  on `undefined` (`undefined` is the default return value).
        // This would throw an error.
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            switch (stage) {
                case 'zero':
                    // some code
                    newStage = 'one';
                    resolve(newStage); // you must call `resolve`
                case 'one':
                    return MyStatusModule.getApiTwo('foo').then(function (response) {
                        // console.log(response);
                        newStage = 'two';
                        /********************************************
                        I assume, the problem lies here, it's 
                        'resolving' (below) before this sets the new 
                        value for 'newStage'
                        ********************************************/
                        resolve(newStage); // you must call `resolve`
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    // do nothing
                    resolve(newStage); // you must call `resolve`
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
    
    // tests:
    function logPromise(){
        var a=arguments, input = a[a.length-1|0];
        if (isPromise(input)) { 
            for (var c=[null], i=0; i<(a.length-1|0); i=i+1|0) c.push(a[i]);
            return input.then(logPromise.bind.apply(logPromise, c));
        } else console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
    
    logPromise("test->test: ", someFunction({id: 1, someValue: 'test'})); // sets 'stage' to 'test'
    logPromise("hello->zero: ", someFunction({id: 1, someValue: 'hello'})) // sets 'stage' to 'zero'
    .finally(function(){ // `.finally` is like `.then` without arguments
                         // This `.finally` waits until the HTTP request is done
        logPromise("foo->one: ", someFunction({id: 1, someValue: 'foo'})) // sets 'stage' to 'one'
        .finally(function(){
            debugger;
            logPromise("bar->two: ", someFunction({id: 1, someValue: 'bar'})); // NOT setting 'stage' to 'two'
        });
    });
});
```

If it is not apparent already, do not copy the above snippet into your code. It will break your code because the above snippet is rigged with dummy Node modules designed to produce set results. Instead, copy each individual file (each wrapped in a function) from the snippet above into the corresponding file of your code if you must copy. Also, while copying, keep in mind not to copy the dummy stuff above the blatant `IGNORE ALL CODE ABOVE THIS LINE` indicator. Also, do not forget to test rigorously. I am much more familiar with browser JavaScript than Node JavaScript, so it is possible (though unlikely) that I may have introduced a potential source of errors.

## `someObject[inputObject.id] = objectForThis;` is not needed

I *could* give you a super concise quick answer to this question. However, I feel that the "quick" answer would not do you justice because this particular question requires a far greater depth of understanding to be able come up with an explanation than to simply read someone else's explanation. Further, this is a very crucial concept in Javascript. Thus, it is very necessary to be able to come up with the explanation on your own so that you do not run into the same trouble again 5 minutes from now. Thus I have written the below tutorial to guide you to the answer so that you can be sure that you have complete understanding.

In Javascript, there are expressions such as `7 - 4` which yields `3`. Each expression returns a value that may be used by further expressions. `3 * (4 + 1)` first evaluates `4 + 1` into `3 * 5`, then that yields `15`. Assignment expressions (`=`,`+=`,`-=`,`*=`,`/=`,`%=`,`**=`,`&=`,`|=`, and `^=`) only change the left-hand variable. Any right-hand variable stays the exact same and contains the same value:

```js
var p = {};
var ptr = p;
// Checkpoint A:
console.log('Checkpoint A: p === ptr is now ' + (p === ptr));
ptr = null;
// Checkpoint B:
console.log('Checkpoint B: p === ptr is now ' + (p === ptr));
```

Let us examine what `p` and `ptr` look like at Checkpoint A.

[image]

As seen in the above diagram, both `p` and `ptr` are kept separate even though they both point to the same object. Thus, at Checkpoint B, changing `ptr` to a different value does not change `p` to a different value. At Checkpoint B, variable `p` has remained unchanged while `ptr` is now `null`.

At Checkpoint A, keep in mind that (although `p` and `ptr` are distinct variables with different memory addresses) `p` and `ptr` both point to the same object because the location in memory they point to is the same index number. Thus, if we changed this object at checkpoint A, then reading/writing the properties of `p` would be the same as reading/writing the properties of `ptr` because you are changing the data being pointed to, not which variable is pointing to what data.

```js
function visualize(inputObject) {
   // displays an object as a human-readable JSON string
   return JSON.stringify(inputObject);
}

var p = {};
p.hello = "world";
// Checkpoint 0:
console.log('Checkpoint 0: p is ' + visualize(p));
var ptr = p;
ptr.foo = "bar";
// Checkpoint A:
console.log('Checkpoint A: p is ' + visualize(p) + ' while ptr is ' + visualize(ptr));
ptr = null;
// Checkpoint B:
console.log('Checkpoint B: p is ' + visualize(p) + ' while ptr is ' + visualize(ptr));
p.foo = p.hello;
// Checkpoint C:
console.log('Checkpoint C: p is ' + visualize(p) + ' while ptr is ' + visualize(ptr));
```

As seen at Checkpoint A above, changing `p` is the same as changing `ptr`. What about when we reassign an object? The old object which is no longer pointed to get cleaned up by tan automatic Garbage Collector.

```js
function visualize(inputObject) {
   // displays an object as a human-readable JSON string
   return JSON.stringify(inputObject);
}

var first = {one: "is first"};
first = {uno: "es el primero"};

var second = {two: "is second"};
second = first;

console.log("second is " + JSON.stringify(second));
```

Function arguments are the same as variables in this respect.

```
var obj = {};

setVariable(obj);

obj.key = "value";
console.log("obj is " + JSON.stringify(obj));

function setVariable(inputVariable){
     inputVariable.setValue = "set variable value";
     inputVariable = null;
}
```

Is the same as:

```js
var obj = {};

/*function setVariable(*/ var inputVariable = obj; /*){*/
    inputVariable.setValue = "set variable value";
    inputVariable = null;
/*}*/

obj.key = "value";
console.log("obj is " + JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Objects are also no different:

```js
function visualize(inputObject) {
   // displays an object as a human-readable JSON string
   return JSON.stringify(inputObject);
}
var variables = {};
var aliasVars = variables;
// Now, `variables` points to the same object as `aliasVars`

variables.p = {};
aliasVars.p.hello = "world";
// Checkpoint 0:
console.log('Checkpoint 0: variables are ' + visualize(variables));
console.log('Checkpoint 0: aliasVars are ' + visualize(aliasVars));
variables.ptr = aliasVars.p;
aliasVars.ptr.foo = "bar";
// Checkpoint A:
console.log('Checkpoint A: variables are ' + visualize(variables));
console.log('Checkpoint A: aliasVars are ' + visualize(aliasVars));
variables.ptr = null;
// Checkpoint B:
console.log('Checkpoint B: variables are ' + visualize(variables));
console.log('Checkpoint B: aliasVars are ' + visualize(aliasVars));
aliasVars.p.foo = variables.p.hello;
// Checkpoint C:
console.log('Checkpoint C: variables are ' + visualize(variables));
console.log('Checkpoint C: aliasVars are ' + visualize(aliasVars));
```

Next is object notation just to make sure that we are on the same page.

```
var obj = {};
obj.one = 1;
obj.two = 2;
console.log( "obj is " + JSON.stringify(obj) );
```

is the same as

```
var obj = {one: 1, two: 2};
console.log( "obj is " + JSON.stringify(obj) );
```

is the same as

```
console.log( "obj is " + JSON.stringify({one: 1, two: 2}) );
```

is the same as

```js
console.log( "obj is {\"one\":1,\"two\":2}" );
```

The `hasOwnProperty` allows us to determine whether or not an object has a property.

```js
var obj = {};
// Checkpoint A:
console.log("Checkpoint A: obj.hasOwnProperty(\"hello\") is " + obj.hasOwnProperty("hello"));
console.log("Checkpoint A: obj[\"hello\"] is " + obj["hello"]);

obj.hello = "world"; // now set the variable
// Checkpoint B:
console.log("Checkpoint B: obj.hasOwnProperty(\"hello\") is " + obj.hasOwnProperty("hello"));
console.log("Checkpoint B: obj[\"hello\"] is " + obj["hello"]);

obj.hello = undefined;
// Checkpoint C:
console.log("Checkpoint C: obj.hasOwnProperty(\"hello\") is " + obj.hasOwnProperty("hello"));
console.log("Checkpoint C: obj[\"hello\"] is " + obj["hello"]);

delete obj.hello;
// Checkpoint D:
console.log("Checkpoint D: obj.hasOwnProperty(\"hello\") is " + obj.hasOwnProperty("hello"));
console.log("Checkpoint D: obj[\"hello\"] is " + obj["hello"]);
```

Prototypes in javascript are crucial to understanding `hasOwnProperty` and work as follows: when a property is not found in an object, the object's __proto__ is checked for the object. When the object's __proto__ does not have the property, the object's __proto__'s __proto__ is checked for the property. Only after an object without a __proto__ is reached does the browser assume that the wanted property does not exist. The __proto__ is visualized below.

```js
var obj = {};
console.log('A: obj.hasOwnProperty("foo") is ' + obj.hasOwnProperty("foo"));
console.log('A: obj.foo is ' + obj.foo);

obj.__proto__ = {
    foo: 'value first'
};
console.log('B: obj.hasOwnProperty("foo") is ' + obj.hasOwnProperty("foo"));
console.log('B: obj.foo is ' + obj.foo);

obj.foo = 'value second';
console.log('C: obj.hasOwnProperty("foo") is ' + obj.hasOwnProperty("foo"));
console.log('C: obj.foo is ' + obj.foo);

delete obj.foo;
console.log('D: obj.hasOwnProperty("foo") is ' + obj.hasOwnProperty("foo"));
console.log('D: obj.foo is ' + obj.foo);

delete obj.__proto__.foo;
console.log('E: obj.hasOwnProperty("foo") is ' + obj.hasOwnProperty("foo"));
console.log('E: obj.foo is ' + obj.foo);
```

Infact, we could even store a reference to the __proto__ and share this reference between objects.

```js
var dog = {noise: "barks"};
var cat = {noise: "meow"};
var mammal = {animal: true};

dog.__proto__ = mammal;
cat.__proto__ = mammal;

console.log("dog.noise is " + dog.noise);
console.log("dog.animal is " + dog.animal);

dog.wagsTail = true;
cat.clawsSofa = true;
mammal.domesticated = true;

console.log("dog.wagsTail is " + dog.wagsTail);
console.log("dog.clawsSofa is " + dog.clawsSofa);
console.log("dog.domesticated is " + dog.domesticated);

console.log("cat.wagsTail is " + cat.wagsTail);
console.log("cat.clawsSofa is " + cat.clawsSofa);
console.log("cat.domesticated is " + cat.domesticated);
```

However, the above syntax is terribly illperformant because it is bad to change the __proto__ after the object has been created. Thus, the solution is to set the __proto__ along with the creation of the object. This is called a constructor.

```js
function Mammal(){}
// Notice how Mammal is a function, so you must do Mammal.prototype
Mammal.prototype.animal = true;

var dog = new Mammal();
// Notice how dog is an instance object of Mammal, so do NOT do dog.prototype
dog.noise = "bark";
var cat = new Mammal();
cat.noise = "meow";

console.log("dog.__proto__ is Mammal is " + (dog.__proto__===Mammal));
console.log("cat.__proto__ is Mammal is " + (cat.__proto__===Mammal));

console.log("dog.__proto__ is Mammal.prototype is " + (dog.__proto__===Mammal.prototype));
console.log("cat.__proto__ is Mammal.prototype is " + (cat.__proto__===Mammal.prototype));

console.log("dog.noise is " + dog.noise);
console.log("dog.animal is " + dog.animal);

dog.wagsTail = true;
cat.clawsSofa = true;
Mammal.prototype.domesticated = true;

console.log("dog.wagsTail is " + dog.wagsTail);
console.log("dog.clawsSofa is " + dog.clawsSofa);
console.log("dog.domesticated is " + dog.domesticated);

console.log("cat.wagsTail is " + cat.wagsTail);
console.log("cat.clawsSofa is " + cat.clawsSofa);
console.log("cat.domesticated is " + cat.domesticated);
```

Next, the `this` object in Javascript is not a reference to the instance like in Java. Rather, the `this` in Javascript refers to the `object` in the expression `object.property()` when functions are called this way. When functions are not called this way, the `this` object refers to `undefined` in strict mode or `window` in loose mode.

```js
"use strict"; // "use strict"; at the VERY top of the file ensures strict mode
function logThis(title){
    console.log(title + "`this === undefined` as " + (this === undefined));
    if (this !== undefined) console.log(title + "`this.example_random_name` as " + this.example_random_name);
}
logThis.example_random_name = "log this raw function";
logThis("logThis() has ");

var wrapper = {logThis: logThis, example_random_name: "wrapper around logThis"};
wrapper.logThis("wrapper.logThis has ");
   
var outer = {wrapper: wrapper, example_random_name: "outer wrap arounde"};
outer.wrapper.logThis("outer.wrapper.logThis has ");
```

We can finally take all this knowledge and extrapolate it out to the real example.

```js
var someObject = {};

function someFunction(inputObject) {
   if (!someObject.hasOwnProperty(inputObject.id)) {
       someObject[inputObject.id] = {};
       someObject[inputObject.id].contact = {};
    }

    // get object
    var objectForThis = someObject[inputObject.id];

    objectForThis.stage = inputObject.stage;
}

var setTo = {};
setTo.id = 1;
setTo.stage = "first stage";
someFunction(setTo);

console.log("someObject is " + JSON.stringify(someObject));
```

First, let us inline the function and the `setTo`

```js
var someObject = {};

var setTo = {id: 1, stage: "first stage"};

/*function someFunction(*/ var inputObject = setTo; /*) {*/
   if (!someObject.hasOwnProperty(inputObject.id)) {
       someObject[inputObject.id] = {};
       someObject[inputObject.id].contact = {};
    }

    // get object
    var objectForThis = someObject[inputObject.id];

    objectForThis.stage = inputObject.stage;
/*}*/

console.log("someObject is " + JSON.stringify(someObject));
```

Next, let us inline the `setTo` object.

```
var someObject = {};

var setTo = {id: 1, stage: "first stage"};

if (!someObject.hasOwnProperty(setTo.id)) {
   someObject[setTo.id] = {};
   someObject[setTo.id].contact = {};
}

// get object
var objectForThis = someObject[setTo.id];

objectForThis.stage = setTo.stage;

console.log("someObject is " + JSON.stringify(someObject));
```

Then:

```js
var someObject = {};

if (!someObject.hasOwnProperty(1)) {
   someObject[1] = {};
   someObject[1].contact = {};
}

// get object
var objectForThis = someObject[1];

objectForThis.stage = "first stage";

console.log("someObject is " + JSON.stringify(someObject));
```

To visually demonstrate the pointers:

```js
var someObject = {};


if (!someObject.hasOwnProperty(1)) {
   var createdObject = {};
  
   someObject[1] = createdObject;
   someObject[1].contact = {};
}

// get object
var objectForThis = someObject[1];
console.log("createdObject === objectForThis is " + (createdObject === objectForThis));

objectForThis.stage = "first stage";

console.log("someObject is " + JSON.stringify(someObject));
```

Please tell me if you have any further questions.

If you are just glancing at this, then please don't forget to read the full article above. I promise you that my article above is shorter and tries to go deeper into Javascript than any other article you may find elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: Thanks! Question: inside the `someFunction(){...}` function, how do you set the `objectForThis` back to `someObject[inputObject.id]`?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs `objectForThis` does not need to be reassigned back to `someObject[inputObject.id]` because Javascript uses pass-by-reference objects. Please read the article I wrote for you and appended to my answer above. Also, if you found my question helpful then please do not forgot to upvote my question and mark it as the accepted answer. Otherwise, please don't forget to upvote the other answer and accept it.

Comment: Wow great answer! And thanks for the further explanation (yes, for me it would have been required to understand that better)!

Comment: This actually helps a bit more: I don't think I'll need the `Promise` on some functionality, since I only did it to return the stage. Though in my example I'm calling all the function multiple times consecutively, this will not be the case in real life, as this will be responding to text messages for a Message Bot.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs Glad I could help. Reducing the number of promises in your program will definitely help your program's performance. For more info, reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/48256045#48256045 might be worthwhile for familiarizing yourself with the various ways to declare a javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

No, your `someOtherFunction` [should not use `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). You should just chain onto the `status.getApiTwo('foo')` call, or create immediately resolved promises using `Promise.resolve`. That way it will always return a promise like your call in `someFunction` expects it.

```
function someOtherFunction(stage) {
    switch (stage) {
        case 'zero':
            // some code
            return Promise.resolve('one');
        case 'one':
            return status.getApiTwo('foo').then(response => {
//          ^^^^^^
                console.log(response);
                return 'two';
//              ^^^^^^
            });
        default:
            // do nothing
            return Promise.resolve(undefined);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use `async`/`await`:

```
async function someOtherFunction(stage) {
    switch (stage) {
        case 'zero':
            // some code
            return 'one';
        case 'one':
            const response = await status.getApiTwo('foo');
            console.log(response);
            return 'two';
        default:
            // do nothing
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this worked! I'll test some more before finalizing.

Comment: Though it worked! I gave Jack Giffen credit for a thorough answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232156/286618). Thanks!